# Show FrameView after HIDE_ON_CLOSE

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, desktop-application, show-hide

I have a problem with my Java app, I set the necessary for reduce to icon in traybar and set:

```
app.getMainFrame().setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
```

So when I close my app in taskbar will be close, but the app continue to run and it's visible the icon to taskbar.

The problem is: How can I restore the app from the taskbar?

I tried:

```
app.show(app.getMainView().getFrame());
app.getMainView().getFrame().setVisible(true);
app.getMainView().getFrame()setVisible(true);
```

but neither of them worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to restore it to the default state:

```
app.getMainFrame().setVisible(true);
app.getMainFrame().setState(Frame.NORMAL);
```

---

Edit: tested this with a `JFrame` and it works fine. See:

```
JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
while (true) {
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setState(JFrame.NORMAL);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This basically just shows the `JFrame` as soon as it is hidden.

Comment: argh I tried, but no work...
the app is a 
    
    SingleFrameApplication extends FrameView